# Is there any reason why facebook uses url fragment(#) in redirect urls?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook-php-sdk for facebook integration on my site. I am generating a login url from facebook using their api function [getLoginUrl()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/), passing a params array in the parameter. The params array contains a key called redirect_uri.

When the user clicks on the facebook connect button on my site it links to the login url provided above from facebook. Facebook then authenticates the user and it redirects the user's browser back to the redirect_uri I specify in params. This url contains GET parameters and a url fragment `#_=_` in the end. Why does facebook add a url fragment at the end of the redirected url. Is there some way to avoid the url fragment?

Comment: With that `_=_` do you mean it follows the https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/ structure?